# From email address find the user in multi-domain AD environment

Tags: active-directory

I have an email address, and now I want to find in multi-domain AD environment the user that owns this email address.

Is there any other way than querying all AD domains, one by one? If not, then how can I find the list of AD domains available?

First, I thought the upn and the primary email adress to be the same, which - of course - is a misconception. 
I also tried to guesstimate the ad domain to be `intra.contoso.com` for all email addresses ending on `intra.contoso.com`, but this is another misconception... :(

For a start, only getting from the primary email address to the user (UPN or SID) would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the global catalog, serach from RootDSE for `mail` attribute and you should see your results. If that is an Exchange account, you should get no more than one hit. The UPN is not necessarily the email address, if your admin did not configure explicit UPNs (namely, company-wide email addresses aka enterprise principals).

Comment: `DirectoryEntry("GC://RootDSE")` does not support search, or so the error says.

Comment: `DirectoryEntry("GC://rootDSE/")` (with small R(!) and final slash(!)) does support search, but the error now is `Unknown Error (0x80005000)`

Comment: You can always use: `ldap://<fqdn-of-forest>:3268`. That works here. `RootDSE` is implied.

Comment: `DirectorySearcher(DirectoryEntry("GC:").Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().First())` works in our test environment, perhaps someone could explain to me what happens there?

Comment: @Alexander, you would try Softerra LDAP Browser before start coding. A very nice tool for Windows.